# Connecting to WiFi immediately results in disconnection

Tags: wireless, usb, network-manager

I'm using Kubuntu 16.04 on a laptop, and I face a strange problem. I have an internal WiFi card as well as a USB WiFi dongle. I prefer to connect to WiFi using the dongle because the internal WiFi is unreliable and gives spotty connection. However, when I try to connect to eduroam (WPA2-PEAP) using the USB WiFi, the network-manager disconnects wifi altogether (WiFi is on, but whole network-manager screen is blank) as soon as it first connects to the WiFi (e.g. opening homepage / page refresh / dropbox connecting etc). However, it doesn't happen with the internal WiFi card. I have to use `sudo service network-manager restart` for making all WiFi networks visible again.

Comment: Is the driver for the internal device blacklisted or is it loading and possibly conflicting?

Comment: @chili555 How do I find it out?

Comment: Run the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Does it show a kernel driver in use? Is it loaded? `lsmod` If it is, I'll suggest you blacklist it to see if the performance improves.

Comment: `08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
        DeviceName: Realtek RTL8188EE 802.11b/g/n 1x1Wi-Fi Adapter
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804b]
`

Comment: And is some driver loaded? `lsmod | grep rtl`

Comment: @chili555 `rtl8188ee              86016  0` `rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8188ee` `rtlwifi                77824  2 rtl_pci,rtl8188ee` `mac80211              737280  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8188ee` `cfg80211              565248  3 mac80211,rtlwifi,r8188eu`
`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you unload the driver for the internal device:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8188ee
```

And blacklist it:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8188ee"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Any improvement? It may take a reboot.

Comment: I see, I'll look into that. But if I understand correctly, it will improve the performance of the internal wifi card, right? How do I solve the original problem?

Comment: No. It will disable the internal in order to get the USB to work correctly. Don't worry, if need be, it is easily reversible.